# S#arp architecture equivalent in Java

Tags: java, .net, s#arp-architecture

What’s the equivalent of [S#arp architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/)(.net) in the java world.

A one stop package that encompasses all the best practices and well identified packages to start a web application project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-stop package that handles ORMs, web framework, presentation etc., then several options exist in the Java world. Two widely used, but very different ones are:

1. [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/) + [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org)
2. [Grails](http://grails.org/)

You'll find other frameworks such as [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) or [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) which are geared towards web applications. I can't advise on these other than to say they (again) are widely used and you probably need to perform more investigation.

All the above will ultimately rest atop the base-level Java [Servlet framework](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/), which is probably too low-level for your needs (but worth knowing about).